# Is it possible to remove a Password from a PDF file using PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, passwords

I would like to ask if it's possible to use PHP in removing a password from a password-protected PDF file in which I already know the password? I've seen [this page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/removing-password-from-pdf-on-linux/) which provides many options but using bash script. :( I was required to use PHP as much as possible. Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: you can do it with the help of java find my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530714/how-to-open-the-secured-pdf-with-php-script/36568158#36568158

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Of course it's possible, all you need to do is reverse engineer the encryption and compression and implement the reverse operations in PHP - but why bother:

```
<?php
   `gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=unencrypted.pdf -c .setpdfwrite -f encrypted.pdf`;
?>
```

C.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. Yeah, I found this also on the link I posted above. I was getting the same error as this http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/removing-password-from-pdf-on-linux/#comment-47555 though.

Comment: If you know the password you can add `-sPDFPassword=yourpassword` to the gs command.

Comment: you need to write it in exec with option -sPDFPassword=yourpassword as @SimonSobisch suggested

Answer (score 1):

I use `qpdf` on linux to remove pdf password. To install run:

```
sudo apt install qpdf
```

Here is the function which invokes `qpdf` from php:

```
function removePdfPassword($inFilePath, $password, $outFilePath)
{
    if (empty($inFilePath) || empty($password) || !file_exists($inFilePath)) {
        return false;
    }

    $cmd = 'qpdf -password=' . escapeshellarg($password) . ' -decrypt ' . escapeshellarg($inFilePath) . ' ' . escapeshellarg($outFilePath);

    exec($cmd, $output, $retcode);
    $success = $retcode == 0;

    if (!$success) {
        @unlink($outFilePath);
    }

    return $success;
}
```