# how to open the secured pdf with PHP script

Tags: php, pdf

I am working on a project, where the user can upload a password protected pdf file. There is also a form, where the user can provide a password for it.

Is there any way to open this password protected pdf with PHP?

Comment: What do you mean with "open [...] with PHP script"? What do you want to do with the document then?

Comment: @Setasign:open means read whole pdf through php and output content as text.actualy i'm working on a income tax project where user upload their income tax detail pdf and i want to fetch their information from that pdf.

Comment: plz guys help me on this issue.

Comment: I exactly looking for this: how to preview a protected PDF to a user without asking them to enter the password. handle the password by php code, it will help to make sure after downloading the PDF, users can't open it cause there is a random password set on File, they can only have a preview

Comment: by using https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/ i got what i wan @};-

Answer (score 3):

you can do it by using simple java program and calling executable jar file from your PHP script.
You need pdfbox.jar file to remove password from PDF file,that you can download from https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi. In this example you get a textfile,you can also generate PDF file after unlocking.

```
package pdftotext;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;


public class PdfTotext {

public static void main(String[] args) {
String filename = args[0];
String password = args[1];
PDDocument pd;
BufferedWriter wr;  
try {
        File input = new File(filename);  // The PDF file from where you would like to extract
        File output = new File("unlock.txt"); // The text file where you are going to store the extracted data
        pd = PDDocument.load(input,password);

        pd.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
        PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(output)));
        stripper.writeText(pd, wr);
        if (pd != null) {
            pd.close();
       }
      wr.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
}
```

In PHP script you need to pass filename and password

```
<?php exec("java -jar pdfTotext.jar filename.pdf password"); ?>
```

make sure that executable jar file,library file and pdf file are in same folder.

Comment: Hi, I was searching on how to achieve this functionality and I landed on your answer. How exactly do I call public class PdfTotext from PHP?

Comment: I got it to work by creating a separate jar that utilizes the pdfbox lib and calling that jar in my code

Answer (score 0):

We offer a product called [SetaPDF-Extractor](http://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-extractor/details/), that is able to extract text from PDF documents in PHP. Please notice that it is not free. It also allows you to extract text from protected documents if you are authenticated correctly. Following code is just some dummy logic but should show what's possible. The details about authentication can be found [here](http://manuals.setasign.com/setapdf-core-manual/standard-encryption/#index-4):

```
<?php
require_once("library/SetaPDF/Autoload.php");

// create a document instance
$document = SetaPDF_Core_Document::loadByFilename("Laboratory-Report.pdf");

if ($document->hasSecHandler()) {
    // get the security handler
    $secHandler = $document->getSecHandler();

    // auth by the user password
    if (!$secHandler->authByUserPassword('a secret password')) {
        // ... not authenticated
    }

    // auth by the owner password
    if (!$secHandler->authByOwnerPassword('another secret password')) {
        // ... not authenticated
    }

    // stop at least here if you are not authenticated
}

// create an extractor instance
$extractor = new SetaPDF_Extractor($document);

// get the plain text from page 1
$result = $extractor->getResultByPageNumber(1);

// output
echo '<pre>';
echo htmlspecialchars($result);
echo '</pre>';
```