# Ghostscript outputs blank PDF page when trying to remove protection

Tags: php, pdf, ghostscript

I'm trying to *remove a protection layer* of a `PDF` using `PHP` and following the method suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950246/is-it-possible-to-remove-a-password-from-a-pdf-file-using-php).

But for some reasons, the output `PDF` file becomes a blank page. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

This is the code:

```
$cmd = "gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH 
       -sDEVICE=pdfwrite 
       -sOutputFile='".$filepath."' 
       -c .setpdfwrite 
       -f '".$filepath."'";
$result = exec($cmd);
```

**UPDATE**

[Deleted wrong file]

**UPDATE 2**

Sorry, I think I uploaded the wrong file. [This one should be the one](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ls1ybnyc9versxo/protected.pdf?dl=0) with password protection (or anything of sorts that is not readable).

I'm on Linux and the GS version is `Ghostscript 8.70`

Comment: You are mentioning a *protection layer*. Do you mean standard password protection? Or is some other mechanism used? If you are not sure, please supply the PDF in question for analysis.

Comment: Yes it is password-protected that I meant, file shared above

Comment: The file `SCAN_20160108_022033_568f554290eb6_scan_20160108_021616_568f543c301d8_tmp_20160108_091443_568f39651db6b_remittance-117149-2016-01-08.pdf` you shared is not password-protected.

Comment: I agree, this file is not encrypted. Also, running ot through Ghostscript to the pdfwrite device does not result in a PDF which has a blank page.

Comment: You don't say what OS you are using (I'm assuming some flavour of Linux) and you don't say what version of GS you are using. You should also try from the command line in case your PHP environment differs in some way (the environment may mean it is using a different version of GS for example)

Comment: Sorry everyone - I clearly uploaded the wrong file. I've updated the question with the right file :)

Comment: The new upload [protected.pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ls1ybnyc9versxo/protected.pdf?dl=0) is not a PDF but some container format (IPM.Microsoft Mail.Note) containing a PDF. And the contained PDF is completely unprotected.

Comment: The container format actually is a Microsoft TNEF container... the dreaded `winmail.dat` attachment one sometimes receives from Outlook users.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost certainly going to have to share the PDF file. Also, unless you own the copyright to the file, 'removing protection' is illegal under the DMCA.

If you do own the copyright, why not simply remake the PDF file without protection.

Why are you using PHP instead of running the from the command sahell ?

Comment: I've shared the PDF file above. My app receives PDF files through an email inbox that our suppliers send invoices to. Some of them generate invoices using an automated software and for some reasons their invoices get password-protected while others don't.

Answer (score 0):

Try with qpdf

```
qpdf --password=YOURPASSWORD-HERE --decrypt input.pdf output.pdf
```

Reference: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/removing-password-from-pdf-on-linux/